# How can I list posts which have a particular tag, but didn't have it when originally asked?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I would like to gather some hard data on the use / misuse / non-use of some particular tags. I need a Data.SE query, customisable by tag, which can provide me with a list of all posts which:

- have had that tag edited into them,
- but did not have that tag when originally asked.

This would allow me to confirm or reject the hypothesis that particular tags or types of tags are (or aren't) being discovered and used appropriately by askers on a particular site.

Is there such a Data.SE query? If not, can one of the Data.SE gurus whip one up for me? (Non-coder here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by querying the PostHistory table. The rows with PostHistoryTypeid = 3 will hold the initial tags. The rows with PostHistoryTypeid = 6 will hold the tags on subsequent edits. The Text field of those rows hold the tags in the format `<tag1><tag2><tag3>`. So we query for records with type 6 and the tag. And then we remove those rows that happen to have the tag on rows with type 3 for the same postid.

Here is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1310297?tagname=droids)

```
select distinct postid as [Post Link]
from posthistory ph
where posthistorytypeid = 6  -- added tag
and text like concat('%<', ##tagname:string##,'>%')
and not exists ( 
  select postid
  from posthistory 
  where posthistorytypeid = 3  -- initial tag
  and postid = ph.postid 
  and text like concat('%<', ##tagname:string##,'>%')
)
```

When run today this is what it look like for droids:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).